# Access 2d arrays in julia of my own type

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, julia

I have created my own type:

```
type T
   name
   pos
end
```

What i want to do is create a 2d array of this type. This is how i did it:

```
 arr = Array{T}(10,10) #create 2d Array
```

This creates the 2d array (10 by 10) with all the elements being undefined. (im thinking my problem is here)

So when i try to change just one element of the array

```
arr[1,1].name = "Hi"
```

I get this error:
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference

What how I tried to fix the issue is by creating a default instance of T and iterate through the array and set every element equal to the default.

```
  default = T("Hi",1)
 for i = 1:10
   for j = 1:10
   arr[i,j] = default
   end
 end
```

Now, this sets every element in the array to the default value succesfully but now the problem is that if i try to change the value of just one element of the array, every element of the array is changed to that value.

```
arr[2,4].name  ="Hello"
```

After that line all the elements have the value of "Hello".

Is that not how you are supposed to change values in an array? When i do the same on an Int64 2d array everything works how i would expect.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:http://imgur.com/FUE4eab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is working as it should.

```
arr[i,j] = default
```

sets `arr[i,j]` to the reference `default` which is the instance of `T("Hi",1)`. So every single `arr[i,j]` is referring to the same instance of the type.

```
arr[1,1].name = "Hi"
```

does not work because when you do `arr = Array{T}(10,10)` you create a 10x10 empty array with the ability of holding `T`s, but you haven't put any `T`s in there!

Thus what you want to be doing is:

```
arr[i,j] = T("Hi",1)
```

which will both make a `T` and make `a[i,j]` refer to it. Since each line is making a new `T`, they will refer to different instances and act separately.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you for the good explanation and the quick answer.

Comment: If you like the answer, don't forget to hit the checkmark to accept the answer so future users know this has been answered. Welcome to the SO community!